# Partially deserialize with JSON.NET, keeping some fields raw

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, partial

I have a document like this

```
{
    "Field1": 1,
    "Field2": 2,
    "Field3": {
        Type: "TheMotherLoad"
    }
}
```

Which i want to convert into this class, but keeping field 3 "raw/as-is".

```
public class Fields {
    public int Field1 { get; set; }
    public int Field2 { get; set; }
    public string Field3 { get; set; }
}
```

The result should be

```
Field1 = 1, 
Field2 = 2, 
Field3 = "{ Type: "TheMotherLoad" }"
```

Possible with Json.NET?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Field3 could be a JObject. When you need JSON just call Field3.ToString()

Comment: Some people will find `JRaw` suit better, because it's not always the object (might be string or number).