# Json.Net deserialization, keeping some properties unserialized

Tags: json, parsing, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a json string looking something like this:

```
{
    "Bar": { 
        "Pressure":42,
        "ServesDrinks":false
    },
    "Baz":[
        {
            "Pressure":9001,
            "ServesDrinks":true
        },
        {
            "Pressure":0,
            "ServesDrinks":false
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to de-serialize this into a class looking something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raw serialized (un-de-serialized) json string of the Baz list  
    /// </summary>
    public string Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Basically not de-serializing the Baz value and instead storing the raw string.
I.e. I want the `Baz` string value after serialization to be:

> "[{\"Pressure\":9001,\"ServesDrinks\":true},{\"Pressure\":0,\"ServesDrinks\":false}]"

I am using Json.Net but have not managed to figure out how to do this.
In the ideal case I would just like to put a magic attribute on my `Baz` property that retains the raw json.

I have seen a very similar question here: 
[Partially deserialize with JSON.NET, keeping some fields raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15828230/partially-deserialize-with-json-net-keeping-some-fields-raw)

But I did understand how to go with that `JObject` approach.

(If it is of any help, I know that the data I want to retain is a list)

Thankful for any help!

Comment: The other question suggests to change the Baz field to `JObject`, which is a generic type to represent JSON objects. You can get the JSON string with `Baz.ToString()`, and assign to it using `JObject.parse(aJSONString)`.

Comment: Thanks Jakub, however I don't manage to get this working. I get a JsonReaderException : "Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path 'Baz', line 1, position 8."

Comment: You can try `JArray` instead. I looked a little bit at JSON.Net documentation, and it looks like `JArray` is used to handle JS arrays, and `JObject` only works with true JS objects (`{foo: ...}`). I have given a fuller answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer to the other question, it seems that the solution in JSON.Net for cases like this is to use the appropriate `J*` type and use their `ToString()` and `Parse()` methods to work with the JSON string.

For JS lists, the appropriate type seems to be `JArray`, not `JObject`, which is used for `{}` style Javascript objects.

Please note that I know little about JSON.Net, and perhaps there is a different solution which would avoid the need to use `Parse()` and `ToString()` everywhere. Somebody with a better knowledge of that library might give a better answer.